# Proper iOS Background Location Updates

Tags: iphone, ios, gps, core-location, multitasking

Location updates using apples CLLocationManager have been working fine while my application is running.  I decided to implement the MonitorSignificantLocationChanges method described in the apple documentation.

Here is my applicationDidEnterBackground method:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

// Switch to significant location change events monitoring
[self.viewController.locationController.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
[self.viewController.locationController.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

The problem that I am having is that no matter whether I startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges or not, my application still reports to iOS that it is utilizing location updates even when the application has been removed from the multitasking bar.  Just installing the app without ever running it is enough to make iOS display the location icon in the top right of the screen and the phone starts to drain the battery.  I cannot figure out how to properly stop location updates when the home button is pressed and how to properly start the significant change monitoring service.

Please let me know if I can provide any additional helpful details.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug. I managed to fix this by removing the app and reset location warning. After that, if I install the app again, the location arrow does not show up anyway, even after I allow location for the app and close it

Comment: I tried the same steps but this did not solve the problem for me.  Do you mean it is an iOS bug?

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.viewController.locationController.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

You have started significant location updates which will track user's location. This is also one of location manager service. You will continually see the GPS icon in top right corner until you stop this service or delete your app from device.

To stop this service use,

```
[self.viewController.locationController.locationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

Once you stopped significant location updates, the GPS icon will go away...

Please refer [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125), In this check **Getting the User’s Current Location**

Hope this will help you....